# In elementary row operations why is the linear combo condition $R_j +sR_i \to R_j$ and not $rR_j +sR_i \to R_j$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Well I know it would feel like any of the two ways above can be used, but I'm not very sure of this.
The reason is nowhere when ERO is talked about,the linear combo operation is stated as $rR_j +sR_i \to R_j$. It is always given as $R_j + sR_i \to R_j$. (i.e scalar multiple of row $R_j$ is always 1) 
Is this because $rR_j +sR_i \to R_j$ would pose some kind of a problem?

The question might seem trivial but some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: I really tried to understand what you are trying to ask but I don't understand anything you wrote. Can you please clarify the objects and symbols.

Comment: Your suggestion would multiply the determinant by $r$. Put differently: Do you also have a row operation $R_j\to rR_j$ in your utility belt? If so, you can obtain your suggestion as combination of $R_j\to rR_j$ and $R_j+sR_i\to R_j$ (so yours is not so elementary after all)